# ASP .Net Connection Pooling With Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, session, iis-7

Hello all respective genius there, thanks in advance.

I have an Asp.NET Web service which have around 20 to 30 methods to expose .
For database I am using Oracle database with the help of Delete repeated wordNet and a single class for the DB Operation  and for every request I open the connection and close once its job get done for sure , means that I am closing all the connection there is no connection leak in my code. I have checked this like 10 times but as I go and check in the database (Oracle 11G) there are many session are inactive more than 20 hours . I am looking these sessions in V$Session table but I am very confused how they are not getting destroyed after long time even I am closing all the connections .

Please share your answers with me because all I can do close all the connection and that I am doing very well but still there are many inactive session more than 20 hours  . How is this possible ?

Comment: Perhaps you should share the relevant database connection code.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem in asp.net mvc project with connecting to Oracle Database (with pooling).

After a long time we found out the problem was with oracle db-links. If you calling a **stored procedure** which uses oracle db-link then you have to call `DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK('db_link_name');` at the **beginning of stored procedure**.

For example:

```
PROCEDURE simple_procedure(refCur out SYS_REFCURSOR) AS BEGIN

    /* we don't really know if db-link is open or not */
    BEGIN
        DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK('dblink_name');
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN null;
    END;

    /* call db-link */
    OPEN refCur FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL@dblink_name

    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN null;

END simple_procedure;
```

After this problems with session has gone.